# How to get the git refs name directly from gitlab server repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I'm trying to create an update server-side hook script in a local gitlab server.

From my update hook script, I need to get the commit msg as well as the ref name for the new_commit.

From a remote machine, if I run the following command I get the correct value:

```bash
john@machine:/tmp/test-hooks$ git log --format=%d -n 1 632f8f615d5904020b7bf1111d1eda3e163d9af3
 (origin/main, origin/HEAD)
```

But, inside the gitlab server, running the same command in the repository, I'm getting a different value:

```bash
root@71c6482bcfa9:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/d4/73/d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35.git/custom_hooks# git log --format=%d -n 1 632f8f615d5904020b7bf1111d1eda3e163d9af3
 (refs/keep-around/632f8f615d5904020b7bf1111d1eda3e163d9af3)
```

How can I get the same `(origin/main, origin/HEAD)` instead of the `(refs/keep-around/632f8f615d5904020b7bf1111d1eda3e163d9af3)` directly from the gitlab server project repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the same `(origin/main, origin/HEAD)` instead of the `(refs/keep-around/632f8f615d5904020b7bf1111d1eda3e163d9af3)` directly from the gitlab server project repository?

You can't.  The reason is very simple: Git's names aren't "global" (this is not a well-defined Git term, so read on to see what I mean).

You have two different repositories involved here.  One is *your* repository, on your laptop.  The other is *GitLab's repository*, on your GitLab server.

A *Git repository* is mostly made up of two databases, one usually much bigger and one much smaller:

- The big database holds *commits* and other objects.  The "names" of these objects are hash IDs, such as `632f8f615d5904020b7bf1111d1eda3e163d9af3`.  These are how Git finds the objects: you *must* give Git the hash ID.  Those are the keys for the database, which is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database).  But you don't necessarily have to *type in* a raw hash ID, because ...
- The small database holds *names*, such as `origin/main` or `refs/keep-around/632f8f615d5904020b7bf1111d1eda3e163d9af3`.  That last name is very peculiar—it is probably a special GitLab trick.  Most names are either *branch* names, which start with `refs/heads/`, or *tag* names, which start with `refs/tags/`, or sometimes *remote-tracking names*, which start with `refs/remotes/`.<sup>1</sup>

Now, cloning a repository involves copying the entire big database (or most of it), usually.  That's because we need all the commits and their supporting objects, in order to use the repository.  (Sometimes we can get away with a limited, or even very-limited, subset of the objects, but that's an optimization to be done later.)  But when we clone the repository, we *do not* copy the *names* database at all.

Instead, `git clone` takes each of their *branch* names and *changes that name* into a *remote-tracking name*.  This means that if the original repository has `refs/head/main`—which is a branch name—then our clone ends up with `refs/remotes/origin/main`, which is a remote-tracking name.  This gets summarized in `git log` output (and other outputs) by dropping the `refs/remotes/` part *sometimes*.  Some commands, such as `git branch -a`, drop only the `refs/` part.  Why?  Nobody seems to know.  All we know for sure is that the real name starts with `refs/remotes/` and goes on to list `origin/` and then the branch name as seen in the other repository, over there on `origin`.

But that's the basic problem: *they* have `main`; *we* get `origin/main`.  Later, our own Git may create a new branch name in *our* (laptop) repository and use the name `main`, but that's a *different branch name* than their `main`.  Each branch name is *local to the repository that contains it*.

So, just because *we* have an `origin/main` does not mean that *they* have an `origin/main`.  Moreover, we might have an `origin/main` because at some point in the *past*, they *used to have* a `main`, but now they don't any more.  Our remote-tracking names, in our laptop repository, get stale and out-of-date.

Meanwhile, they have a special (weird / funny) name-space, `refs/keep-around/`.  Our `git clone` command *may* be able to see these names, if they choose to list them for us at `git clone` and `git fetch` time.  But our Git *software* doesn't *put* that name into our repository's smaller names database, because it's an unrecognizable name: it doesn't start with `refs/heads/` or `refs/tags/` and those are the only names *our* Git look at when *their* Git tells us that they have them.  For other names, our Git software just says "yeah okay but [fuggedaboutit](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fuggedaboutit)!"

In short, then, you can't get what you want, because it simply doesn't exist.  When you're using Git, you *must understand this*.  If you don't, you will have the kind of time you're having.

> From my update hook script, I need to get the commit msg as well as the ref name for the new_commit.

When someone runs `git push`, they:

- deliver some objects for your Git to put in your objects database, if necessary (perhaps you already have all the objects); then
- ask (politely) or command (forcefully) that your Git software create or update some name(s) in your names database.

The update hook, if you have one, is run with an *argument* specifying the name that your Git was asked or commanded to create or update.  It also gets:

- the current hash ID associated with that name, if any; and
- the new hash ID the other Git asked or commanded yours to associate with the name.

That's all you get.  At most one of the existing and new hash IDs may be all-zeros, indicating a new name being created or an existing name being deleted.

You cannot see the other Git repository's names, if any, for this commit.  Those are in *their* names database, not in yours.  You're being asked or commanded to update *your* names database.  You can pass judgement now, and either allow or deny the operation to proceed.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  I like to drop the word *branch* from this phrase as it's serving no useful purpose and tends to confuse humans: they think these are branch names, but they're not, they are only remote-tracking (or "remote-tracking-branch") names.  That is, they are names, of a "tracking-ish" type, specifically the "remote-tracking" type.  The verb *track* is overused in Git as well, but the things that these names track are some other repository's branch names.